# Почему блоки не меняют свою ширину?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i = 0; i > elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.width = '100px';
  });
};
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Блок должен менять свою ширину при клике на него

Comment: по крайней мере, тут `i > elements.length;` должно быть `<`

Comment: Зря в вопросе исправили, тогда становится непонятен сам вопрос, если всё работает. Всё же вопросы так же это возможность ребятам потренироваться поискать ошибки.

Answer (score 6):

Ваш цикл ниразу не срабатывает, так как `i > elements.length`, то есть ваш цикл не проходит ни одну итерацию, необходимо сделать `<`.

Для таких целей лучше всего подходит отладка JavaScript. Нажимаем `F12` -> `Console` и смотрим ошибки. Можно даже в код добавлять вывод в консоль для большей ясности `console.log("some debug info")`